# Experience of the differential equation $y' -y -\ln x =0$ on $(0;+\infty)$ is bounded?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the  differential equation $y' -y -\ln x =0$ on $(0;+\infty)$. Does there exist experience bounded?

I solved $y(x)=e^x(c+\int_{1}^{x}e^{-t}\ln tdt);c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Could you help me to prove that y(x) is bounded or y(x) isn't bounded.

Comment: What do you mean by experience blocked?

Comment: It mean "bounded"

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that by "blocked" you mean bounded. Take $c=0$ in the general solution. If $0<x\le1$, then
$$
\Bigl|\int_1^xe^{-t}\ln t\,dt\Bigr|\le\int_0^1|\ln t|\,dt=1.
$$
If $x>1$ then
$$
\Bigl|\int_1^xe^{-t}\ln t\,dt\Bigr|\le\int_1^\infty t\,e^{-t}\,dt=2\,e^{-1}.
$$
Now it is easy to see that any other solution (with $cºne0$) is unbounded.